# UIActivityViewController does not show link over facebook when shared

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am not able to see the string and the link when I use share functionality over facebook, below is sample code.

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text."], [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
NSArray * applicationActivities = nil;
NSArray * excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeMessage];

UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Link Must be a NSURL Object:

```
NSString *link = @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id00000000";
NSArray *activityItems = @[ [NSURL URLWithString: link] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link is there, but it isn't displayed inline as part of the text of your post. Instead it is seen as an attachment-like preview:

[image]

If you want to see your link in the text, add it to your `NSString` activity item:

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some initial text. An inline link http://www.yahoo.com"]];
```

This way you will see the string and the link:

[image]